# Draw an Image from URL Passed to HTML - Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I have a URL which linked to an image. It's not stored locally.
I've searched hints and still got no progress.
How can I load the image on the HTML page ?

```
Link : https://something.jpg
```

I'm still new in this area. Thank you.

Comment: html - `<img src='your image link' >`

Comment: Thank you.. such a simple solution doesn't across to me.